# PPA for Thunderbird 78 for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: thunderbird

It took a while, until a Thunderbird PPA officially rolled out upgrades to Thunderbird 78. Unfortunately, there is no upgrade for Ubuntu 16.04 so far.

So the question is, is it still worth waiting for an upgrade, or will there be no upgrade, since 16.04 will end next year in April?

Comment: Ubuntu *flavors* and most of the 'universe' repository packages only came with 3 years of support; Ubuntu's 'main' repository comes with 5 years yes, but that's geared at back-porting security fixes only.  Given most attention on *xenial* some time ago (April-2019), I wouldn't wait for it, nor expect it.  That won't mean some who really wants it for themselves won't package it, but I would not expect it.

Comment: Also, if you want a newer version of Thunderbird, you can *generally* just download it and put the binary wherever you want to. You can download [here](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/)  and see [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/installing-thunderbird-linux) for installing outside of the package manager.

Comment: It's provided via *snap* - see https://snapcraft.io/thunderbird

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu *flavors* and most of the 'universe' repository packages only came with 3 years of support; Ubuntu's 'main' repository comes with 5 years yes, but that's geared at back-porting security fixes only.

Given most attention on *xenial* some time ago (April-2019), I wouldn't wait for it, nor expect it.  That won't mean some who really wants it for themselves won't package it, but I would not expect it.

*I didn't expect 16.04.7 ISOs in August-2020, but they were... we don't know what will happen until it does.  No Ubuntu flavor provided 16.04.7 ISOs of course.*

Comment: Note: I don't use, or watch the `thunderbird` package so have no special knowledge. My *opjnion* is just that, opinion on generally what occurs.  I recall a 'universe' package being SRU'd in May-2019, after the *flavors* had already EOL'd 16.04; I just watched the discussions on IRC (-devel rooms) & soon saw the result in an updated package a few weeks after the extended end-of-support (3 years). I wouldn't have predicted that either, but was pleased.